# How to add and share source code files in a WordPress based site?

Tags: wordpress, portfolio

I'm planning a personal/portfolio web site based on WordPress. What I would like to have is a list of example webdev projects/plugins/widgets along with the source code available for browsing in the least obtrusive way (if possible to skip downloading, going to another site, etc).

The alternatives:

- The simplest:

  - Upload the code at github, sourceforge, launchpad, google code, or similar.
  - Share the link to the projects source code in the respective section in my site.
- The easiest:

  - Use an existing WordPress plugin for exposing part of the uploads directory where I can upload the projects' source code.
  - Use a shortcode/widget/custom page for displaying the tree view with the projects and the source code within a WordPress page(s).
- The most realistic:

  - Write the WordPress plugin from above. From my initial research, there is no such plugin for exposing the uploads directory files in the user and/or admin section of a WordPress site.
  - From my initial ideas the plugin is basically a file browser with a fancy tree view and a view panel for the source code file contents
  - (Nice to have) AJAX-ify the plugin to view the source code contents in a DIV with syntax highlighting.

What's your take on this?

Thanks

Comment: For small (one- or two-file) projects, might [Gists](https://gist.github.com/) be an option? Gives you versionable github storage but allows easy embedding of the source code on your site. Nearly as simple as your "simplest" option but easy to put the (syntax-highlighted) code inline on your site.

Comment: Unfortunately, the projects are comprised of multiple files. Thanks for the suggestion, it's nice to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you list as the simplest option is also probably the best. You have all the tools that people are used to -- syntax coloring, etc. -- and all you have to do is make a comment or two and then link to it. This may sound silly, but there is also a certain gravitas lent to your code because it's not "just on some WordPress site".